# shortening the output from the command ps efo cmd | grep

Tags: grep, xterm, ps

I want to condition on whether or not a certain process is running.     The process has a very long description, more or less like

```
/usr/bin/xpdf -remote myXpdfServer -title Bayes2_notes -papercolor cornsilk -geometry 1910x1019+0+29 /home/simon/research/Ward/Bayes2_notes.pdf
```

I sometimes have to use an xterm with a small # of columns, say n.   In this case,if I run ps -ef then grep for some element far out in the tail of this string, ps truncates the string, returning only the first n characters, and my grep command fails.

To fix this, I've tried ps efo cmd | grep etc etc.    This helps some but
not as much as I like.    For example the obvious command to try:

```
ps eco cmd | grep xpdf | grep -v grep
```

returns the following:

|..................................\_ /usr/bin/xpdf -remote myXpdfServer

where those dots denote whitespace which doesn't show up on this forum. I'd very much like to get rid of the garbage, especially the whitespace, at the beginning, i.e., everything that precedes /usr.    Note that piping to cut or sed or something else won't help in this case: the length of the string returned by ps is determined by the number of xterm columns, so shortening this string by post-processing can't help me, because the string I need to examine  has already been truncated by the time that cut gets to do its thing.     I'm sure the only way to do what I want to do is to add some other flag to the ps ef command.

Thanks very much for any advice!

Comment: note `ps -efww` will not truncate output lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ps -ww` provides unlimited width output. You can grep for as much of your command line as you like. If you prefix your string to match with `[ ]` then grep will not match itself. If you add -q to grep there is no output but you can use the return code: it will be 0 if found, 1 otherwise. So

```
if ps alxww | grep -q '[ ]/usr/bin/xpdf -remote myXpdfServer -title Bayes2_notes -papercolor cornsilk -geometry 1910x1019+0+29 /home/simon/research/Ward/Bayes2_notes.pdf'
then echo running
else echo not
fi
```

---

grep in fact matches patterns, not exact strings. In a pattern there are "magic" characters that do not stand for themselves. Fortunately, the command line string you are grepping for has no magic characters, so your pattern just matches exactly the string. Some magic chars are `[`, `*`, `.`, `(`, `+`. In particular the pattern `[ ]` means match the space character. So it is an apparently pointless pattern because it is just the same as a space on its own: " ".

But as you know, doing a `ps|grep string` will find the grep command as well as the command we are interested in. But by using `[ ]`, grep will no longer match its own command because in the output from ps there will be the 3 chars "[ ]" and not the single char " ", so the *pattern* (1 space) will not match.

It's a bit hard to understand. You can read about patterns, which are called *regular expressions*, in `man grep`. They are incredibly useful.

---

When you do `isRunning=$(ps -ef | grep -q '[ ]xpdf ')` your variable is set to an empty string because `grep -q` produces no output. The return code of the last command run by the shell is available in the shell variable `$?`. It will be 0 for true, i.e. the grep matched, or non-zero (usually 1) otherwise.  The value to expect is shown in the *EXIT STATUS* section of  `man grep`.

So if you want to hold on to the result you can do, eg:

```
ps -ef | grep -q '[ ]xpdf '
isRunning=$?
if [ $isRunning = 0 ]
then echo "running. isRunning=$isRunning"
else echo "not. isRunning=$isRunning"
fi
```

Comment: all three pieces of this answer---the ww, the [  ], and the -q flag---are enormously helpful, thanks very much @meuh.    Two followup questions:   1) is this square brackets trick just an ad hoc device added to grep to allow us to avoid  the annoying grep -v grep pipe, or is it an application of a more general syntax? 2),  I would have expected the command isRunning=\`ps -ef | grep -q '[  ]xpdf '\` to return 1 if xpdf is running and zero otherwise, but it doesn't, it seems to return some non-ascii character.   Is there another way to capture the return code?

Comment: I added an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to condition on whether or not a certain process is running.

I would use

```
pidof nameofyourprogram
```

See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof) for the exist status for your condition.

Comment: Thanks for this, katu!    Didn't know that command existed.   Unfortunately, I need to condition not just on the the process name but, additionally, on a filename.    Specifically, I need to condition on whether xpdf is running a certain file.    It would be wonderful if pidof had a "-f" flag like the -f flag for ps, returning the full name of the process.